# Jquery checkbox val array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Html

```
<td>
     <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="t1" checked="checked" class="filter" /><label
                for="t1">T1</label>
</td>
<td>
     <input type="checkbox" value="2" id="t2" checked="checked" class="filter" /><label
                for="t2">T2</label>
</td>
<td>
     <input type="checkbox" value="3" id="t3" checked="checked" class="filter" /><label
                for="t3">T3</label>
</td>
<td>
     <input type="checkbox" value="4" id="t4" checked="checked" class="filter" /><label
                for="t4">Toplam</label>
</td>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".filter").click(function () {
        drawChart();
    });
});

function drawChart()
{
    // I want to get checkboxes value here. 
    var filters = {$("#t1").val(),$("#t2").val(),$("#t3").val(),$("#t4").val()};
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(new google.visualization.DataTable(evalledData, 0.5));
    view.setColumns([0, 4]); //here you set the columns you want to display
}
```

I want to get checkboxes value like above but I dont know correct syntax? Or I would pass array to drawChart. Could you write correct syntax to create an array of checkboxes values?

**Edit**

I want to set view columns with `view.setColumns([0, 4]);` with using checkboxes. I mean I want to use `view.setColumns([array]);` instead of `view.setColumns([0, 4]);`

Thanks.

Comment: Look at what you did, you said array and you have an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myValues = $(".filter").map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get();
console.log(myValues.join(","));
```

If you want only the checked ones:

```
var myValues = $(".filter:checked").map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get();
console.log(myValues.join(","));
```

- http://api.jquery.com/map/

Comment: second one is my solution. How can I use in this function `view.setColumns([0,1,2,3, 4]);`   1,2,3,4 is my chexboxes values.

Comment: `myValues` is an array in the end, so you can just pass it:  `view.setColumns(myValues)`;

Comment: I write `view.setColumns(myValues);` It does not work. But I define an array like this `var array=[1,2,3,4]` and Use it like this : `view.setColumns(array);` It works well. What is the difference between them. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that by value, you actually mean whether the checkbox is checked or not. (A checkbox always has the same value, regardless of whether it's checked or not.)

To get an array of boolean values:

```
var filters = $('.filter').map(function(i, e){
  return $(e).is(':checked');
}).get();
```